# Arduino Function converting char* to byte array

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to create a function in Arduino to convert a string into an array of byte ascii hexadecimal values. I barely understand c, so I apologize for such a complicated way of trying to do what I figure must be simple, but here it goes:

**Input** "AAA"

**Output/Expected result**:  final[ ] = {0x41,0x41,0x41,...}

```
void enviarMsj(const String& message){
  char mensaje[message.length()]; 
  String temp;
  char buf[4];
  uint16_t final[30];
   
  for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
      temp = "0x" + String(message.charAt(i), HEX);
      temp.toCharArray(buf,5);
      final[i]= buf;   
   }
  }
```

Comment: this is not C, it is C++ compiler plus arduino-specific libraries

Comment: It would be better for you to show what your `msg` looks like? and what result you want? because your code simply can't compile and doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The easiness of getting started with an Arduino gave a false impression that you can starting writing programming without much learning of basic data type and C++, but without the understanding of fundamental data type, you tend to write the code that is unnecessary long.

An char array `msg` of `ABCDEF0123456` is an array of `char`, and `char` in C++(and in C) is fundamentally like `uint8_t` or `byte`, a `char` 'A' is stored as an ASCII which has a value of `0x41` in hexadecimal or `65` in decimal.

```
uint8_t byte_of_char_A = (uint8_t) 'A';
```

So if you do `Serial.print(msg[0], HEX)`, you will get the hexadecimal value of `41`.

To create a c string with a prefix of `0x`, you can use the good old [sprintf()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) function.

```
void setup() {
  const char msg[]="ABCDEF01234";

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {}

  char temp[5];
  for (int i=0; i<strlen(msg); i++) {
    sprintf(temp, "0x%x", msg[i]);
    Serial.print(temp);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();

}

void loop() {

}
```

This will print out the result as:

```
0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45 0x46 0x30 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34
```

One more thing about your code, your code won't compile due to mismatching in data type on `final[i]= buf;`. Even if it can compiled successfully, the array `final` is a local declared variable, and it will be gone when the program exit the function, so you need to understand the "scope of a variable" in addition to data type.

I would suggest that you read through [C++ Tutorials](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).

Answer (score -2):

I´m trying to understand what you are trying to do but it think that will not work this way:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(*msg);i++)
{
  byte *msgReady[i] = "0x" + ((int(*msg[i]))-36);
}
```

Possible solution:

```c
do
{
  char data[5];

  data['0'] = '0';
  data['1'] = 'x';

  // If there should be 2 hex characters
  // it is necessary to adapt the calculation
  char nibble_high = *msg / 16;
  
  if(nibble_high > 9)
    nibble_high = 'A' + (nibble_high - 10);

  char nibble_low = *msg % 16;
  
  if(nibble_low > 9)
    nibble_low = 'A' + (nibble_low - 10);

  // Better write a function that does the conversion

  data['2'] = nibble_high;
  data['3'] = nibble_low;

  data['4'] = '\0';  // Only necessary if copied with string functions

  // Copy the data to your msgReady byte array
  // can be done with functions in string.h
  // or manually
  for(unsigned char i=0; i < (sizeof(data) - 1); i++)
  {
    *msgReady = data[i];
    msgReady++;
  }

  // Increment the address of the message array
  msg++;

} while(*msg);    // The msg array has to be '\0' terminated
```

Comment: there are functions to convert number to string in C

Comment: You're right but for learning purpose it's often better to write things without libraries and after that you can use functions in different libraries...